# Client.Bin not update when integrated into ASP.net project

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I am creating a Silverlight application using .Net 4.0 and integrating it into an ASP.net project that created in .Net 3.5.

Whenever I make a change in the Silverlight project the changes are not reflected into the ASP.net project

Answer (score 1):

**You need to ensure your Silverlight app and the website are connected**

Adding it to the solution is not enough. You need to make a Silverlight relationship between the website and your Silverlight application.

- Right-click on your website project and select `Properties`.
- Choose the `Silverlight Applications` tab on the left side
- Press `Add...`
- Leave `Use an existing Silverlight project in the solution` checked and select the project you want to add from the `Project` dropdown.
- Leave `Add a test page that references the control` checked if you want a separate test page for your application.
- Press `Add` and you are done.

The website will now build your Silverlight application and include the output Xap file in its ClientBin folder.

[image: Add Silverlight Application dialog]